# R fscaret package error incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

Having some problems with following the example given in the link 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fscaret/fscaret.pdf

in particular the code

```
myFirstRES <- fscaret(dataset.train, dataset.test, installReqPckg=FALSE,
preprocessData=FALSE, with.labels=TRUE, classPred=FALSE,
regPred=TRUE, skel_outfile=NULL,
impCalcMet="RMSE&MSE", myTimeLimit=5,
Used.funcRegPred=c("lm","pls","pcr"), Used.funcClassPred=NULL,
no.cores=myCores, method="boot", returnResamp="all",
supress.output=TRUE,saveModel=FALSE)
```

gives the error: Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: incorrect number of dimensions

Any ideas what could be the issue, since I followed the example accordingly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: are you able to run the whole code without error?

Comment: Yes, as I said, it runs.

Comment: hmmm r you using R 3.2.2?

Comment: Yes, I use R `3.2.2`, `fscaret` version `0.9.4`.

Comment: Ok it seems that after i set installReqPckg = TRUE, the error disappears,  but now the result is NULL for myFirstRES$PPTrainDF, myFirstRES$PPTestDF,  myFirstRES$PPlabels.. i wonder if it's correct

Comment: If you have set `preprocessData=FALSE`, this is what you should see (`NULL`). Because all `$PP(...)` refer to preprocessed data/models/labels etc.